# why this python code doesn't print anagrams?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_anagram(s1,s2): 
    L1 = list(s1)
    L2 = list(s2)

    return sorted(L1) == sorted(L2)



def read_words():
    fin = open('words.txt')


    for line in fin:
        line = fin.readline()
        word = line.strip()

        for line1 in fin:
            line1 = fin.readline()
            word1 = line1.strip()
            if is_anagram(word,word1):
                print(word, word1)
 read_words()
```

When I run this it doesn't showup anything(not even a error).I am sure that words.txt include some anagrams.I can't figure out why this doesn't work.Please someone help.

words.txt looks like this:

```
aa
aah
aahed
aahing
aahs
aal
aalii
aaliis
aals
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
aardwolves
aas
aasvogel
aasvogels
aba
abaca
abacas
abaci
aback
abacus
abacuses
abaft
abaka
abakas
abalone
abalones
abamp
abampere
abamperes
abamps
abandon
abandoned
abandoning
abandonment
abandonments
abandons
abas
abase
abased
abasedly
abasement
abasements
abaser
abasers
abases
abash
abashed
abashes
abashing
abasing
abatable
abate
abated
abatement
abatements
abater
```

Comment: why you don't show your `word.txt` example? and line which you want to see as result?

Comment: It is a text file with thousands of words.May I copy that list into my question??Bear Brown

Comment: example do you understand what mean example?

Comment: what is your opinion now?? @BearBrown

Comment: good point is add example of the result you want to see, but now you can read the answer.

Comment: I was waiting for your permission.Thank you.@BearBrown

Answer (score 4):

`fin` isn't a list. It only yields each line once. Your two loops aren't going to iterate through it independently.

If you want to iterate through it multiple times, read the lines into a list first. A list can be iterated multiple times.

```
def read_words():
    with open('words.txt') as fin:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in fin]

    for line in lines:
        for line1 in lines:
            if line!=line1 and is_anagram(line, line1):
                print(line,line1)
```

(This assumes that each word is on a separate line in your text file.)